# NOT NULL constraint failed error in django despite having null set to true and blank set to true

Tags: python, django, database, model

Here's the code:

```
class community(models.Model):
    communityName = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    communityID = models.BigIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.communityName

class team(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    startTime = models.TimeField()
    teamName = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    community = models.ForeignKey(community, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

I've done a lot of reading on this and it makes sense that I'm supposed to set null and blank to true to prevent this error however when I attempt to migrate the models I still get the following error thrown:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: scheduler_team.community_id
```

I don't know anything about database management and this is the first project I've attempted to do that has a database involved so an ELI5 would be very much appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it like this in your `team` model:

```
community = models.ForeignKey(community, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  blank=True, null=True)
```

This is the proper way to make it nullable.
When you specify `default=None`, Django ORM does not know if this field is nullable or not.
`community_id` is the field in `team` model and it is (though syntactically implicit) used to refer `community` model by the foreign key in `team` model, and that field was set as not nullable, so that generates *IntegrityError*, if not set.

Comment: Thank you, I was being super dense and just assuming that community_id was the same thing as my field communityID bleh.